# apt-get update error unable to install mongo DB

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, repository

it seems bad luck also likes me.!
i'm trying to install mongo DB but facing issue while updating apt-get repository as below

```
Reading package lists... Done   
E: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.0 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BC711F9BA15703C6
E: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
```

i suspect that something messed up with /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
Can anyone help me how could i resolve this and install mongo DB.

Many Thanks,
Surya Kiran.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version (i.e. 16.04 LTS - xenial, 18.04 LTS - bionic)?

Comment: Hi N0rbert, i resolved it. Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to solve your problem. This works for me:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```